# Bukkit nullpointer config

Tags: java

I am making a bukkit plugin that uses a config to store data, but when I use `plugin.getConfig()` I get a NullPointer. Why? The NullPointer is in the Storage class.

Main: http://pastebin.com/d3bFXbiR

Storage: http://pastebin.com/wvQS3n57

Answer (score 0):

There's only 1 thing that can throw a NullPointerException on that line, and that's the reference to `plugin`.

In your code, you call `Storage.addClickCmd` without ever first constructing the `Storage` instance. The `plugin` field can only be null. When you try to call a method on a null reference you get a NullPointerException.

Comment: When I do it like this if (plugin != null && plugin.getConfig() != null) {System.out.println("Check");} I dont get a message.

Comment: Because plugin is null. Show me the code where you say `new Storage(...`

Answer (score 0):

The Storage.plugin variable is set on the constructor of Storage. This constructor is only called if you create a new *instance* of Storage. You have `plugin` set to *static*, which means you don't need an instance of Storage to access it and therefore you aren't creating one using `new Storage()`. What this means is, while you can *access* the variable, your code never *sets* it. You have two options:

1. Create a *setter* for the `plugin` variable:

This seems to be the solution you need as you have all your methods *static*. First remove the constructor:

```
public Storage(Main instance) {
plugin = instance;
}
```

Then replace it with a setter, which is just a static method, like the other ones in your code:

```
public static void setPlugin(Main instance) {
    plugin = instance;
}
```

2. Set `plugin` and all the methods of Storage to non-static:

This solution follows the object-oriented programming better and can help reset the plugin if the server is reloaded. First make the `plugin` variable and *all the methods* non-static by removing the `static` keywords:

```
    Main plugin;
    ...
      public void addClickCmd(Location loc, String text) {
        ...
      }

      public String getClickCmd(String w, int x, int y, int z) {
        ...
      }

      public String getString(String path) {
        ...
      }
```

Then create a new variable in the Main class which holds the Storage object and set it to a new instance in `onEnable()`:

```
public class Main extends JavaPlugin{

    public Storage storage;
    public void onEnable() {
            final FileConfiguration config = this.getConfig();

            config.options().copyDefaults(true);
            saveConfig();

            storage = new Storage(this);
    }
```

The `this` keyword points to the plugin itself. After that, change the rest of your code to use this new variable:

```
storage.addClickCmd(bl, allArgs);
...
if(storage.getClickCmd(w, x, y, z) != null) {
    String cCc2 = storage.getString(cCc);
```